# how to use many2one field for searching records from other linked model in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I am setting a module with models:

1. Department(department)
2. Registered Business (reg.dept.business)
3. Department Business Records (dept.business.records)

Current working model is `dept.business.records`.

I want to display business list against current department using `business_types` field via calling compute method.

I am unable to filter records based on Domain applying on `search()` in method `get_dept_business_ids()`. All business list are showing currently, if I apply domain there is not result.

```
dept_id = fields.Many2one('department', 'Department')
business_types = fields.Many2many('reg.dept.business', string='Business List', compute='get_firm_business_ids')

@api.multi
def get_dept_business_ids(self):
    for record in self:
        list_val = []
        env_rec = self.env['reg.dept.business'].search([('reg_dept_id', '=', dept_id.id)])
        for x in env_rec:
            list_val.append(x.id)
            record.update({
                'business_types': [(6, False, list_val)]
            })
```

Comment: are you not getting any errors? your search should be ('reg_dept_id', '=', record.dept_id.id). Also you defined compute='get_firm_business_ids' and the name of method you shown here is 'get_dept_business_ids'

Comment: Could you show the model "reg.dept.business" please ?